# Fixed position mask not working in firefox

Tags: css, firefox, mask

So I have a series of section tags all with position relative. Within those tags I have some images and text set with position fixed. In most browsers this creates a nice masking effect. However in fire fox things are stacked on top of each other and the effect just isn't working.

Here is fiddle for reference = http://jsfiddle.net/LmkwxkfL/38/

My sections

```
section{
    padding:20px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
}
```

My imgs

```
.billboard-img {
  width:100%;
  top: 0px;
  left:0px;
  z-index: -1;
  position: fixed;
}
```

Again the above is working in chrome and safari but not in FF. Any help would be great.

Comment: What do you mean by 'masking effect' ? I see just fixed image and text from the fiddle

Comment: Right, in FF I simply looks like a fixed image and text. Open the url in chrome and you should see the sections scrolling on top of each other. Thanks for checking it out.

Comment: Ok so I have tried a couple of things including midnight.js but it wont work for the effect I want. This fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/billNugz/y4x1cbcz/) shows exactly what I want to do but setting the position via JS causes a jitter in safari and IE. Is there any work around with strait css via fixed pos and zindex? And or is there a work around to the jitters in safari and IE?